Is there a way to select the vertices of a mesh by the local axes of another object in geometry nodes?

I want to split the objects in a collection with a boolean and transform one side.
In this case, it seems to be common to use mesh islands to separate geometry.
But this is not useful in this case, because the side with the most vertices changes depending on the position of the cut, and the index changes as well.
The most helpful solution is simply to use the local space of the cutter object, and select the side greater than 0.
(There are other situations where I want to use this way.)
This may be fairly elementary, but I haven't found a way to do this.
Any ideas on this would be helpful.



I think it's self-explanatory.
I guess to really answer the question as in the title:


